# What is the topology of the "character group"?

Tags: general-topology, representation-theory, topological-groups, characters

What is the topology of the "character group"? Is it locally compact (and Hausdorff)? Which book say about them?

Is there a well known topology on the "character group" when the primer group is Abelian and locally compact (Hausdorff)?

Comment: One possibility is Rudin "Fourier Analysis on Groups".

Answer (score 1):

The situation is thus: let $G$ be locally compact abelian and $\Gamma$ be its dual group *i.e.*  its group of continuous characters. The Fourier transform takes functions in $L^1(G)$ to functions on $\Gamma$. If $A$ is the image of $L^1(G)$ under the Fourier transform, then the weak topology induced by $A$ on $\Gamma$ makes $\Gamma$ a locally compact Hausdorff space, and $\Gamma$ is a locally compact abelian topological group. A good reference is Rudin's *Fourier Analysis on Groups*.

Comment: I hear that there is compact open topology on them, what is the relation between this two topology?

Comment: I *think* they agree; it seems quite common to define $\Gamma$ as having the compact-open topology on it, anyway. I think the equivalence to the definition I gave is the content of appendix item D4 in Rudin.

Comment: They do indeed agree. It is easy to see that the the compact open topology is stronger than the weak topology, because the Fourier transform of any L^1 function on G is continuous (and vanishes at infinity) with respect to the compact open topology. 
A proof of the reverse containment can be found in the book "Fourier Analysis on Number fields" by D. Ramakrishnan and J. Valenza, Theorem 3-13 on page 108.